# New wp menu menu styling

Tags: menus, css

Ok ,i am not a great fan of the menu of WP, but now it manage this inside pretty ok, i have to make theme that use that menu. Now for styling i am a bit challenge...

here is the problem... the menu should look like

| page1 | page2 | page 3 |

Do you see the problem, the border, let say each

will be style with border right 1px that work but first item will need a special class for border left

Question. How do i know that it's first or last item in the menu to style it properly... or what is your way to style that type of menu...

Comment: Look like a thing for jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using CSS3?

You could use:

```
ul#navmenuid:first-child {
     border-left: 1px;
}
```

Or you could use (any LI that immediately follows an LI):

```
ul#navmenuid li {
     border-left: 1px;
     border-right: 1px;
}
ul#navmenuid li + li {
     border-left: 0;
}
```

Or you could use (any LI that follow an LI, even if not immediately):

```
ul#navmenuid li {
     border-left: 1px;
     border-right: 1px;
}
ul#navmenuid li ~ li {
     border-left: 0;
}
```

Lots of options via CSS, really...

Comment: it's not really ie6 friendly ?

Comment: Same way you can use JQUERY!

Comment: I stopped caring about IE6 friendliness years ago. At most, I will use IE conditionals to add some margin fixes to correct IE's inconsistent box model, but that's it.